# How to migrate value of nested subdocument in array in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, migrate

I have a Mongoose collection called `Track` that has an array of `fitnessPlan` subdocuments, each of which currently has a `month` field that needs to be changed to `week` in production. I am using `mongoose-migrate` to migrate these values from the old month field to a new week field. Here's what I have got at the moment:

```
async function up () {
  await Track.updateMany({},
    {
      $set: {
        'fitnessPlans.$[elem].month': '$fitnessPlans.$[elem].week',
      },
    },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "elem.week": { $gte: 0 } }], strict: false, });
  
    await Track.updateMany({},
      {
        $unset: {
          'fitnessPlans.$[elem].week': '',
        },
      },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "elem.week": { $gte: 0 } }], strict: false, });
}
```

However, `mongoose-migrate` is throwing the following error:

`Cast to number failed for value "$fitnessPlans.$[elem].week" at path "month"`

I'm guessing this is because the string isn't evaluating correctly, but I'm not sure how else to reference that field's value in this setting.

Comment: you want to just rename the field from month to week? or you need both?

Comment: Yes I want to rename the field but there's no way to use $rename with documents in an array, so you need to do a $set and $unset

Answer (score 0):

Try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `fitnessPlans` array merge objects with current and new created `week` field using `$mergeObjects`
- `$unset` `month` field

```
async function up () {
  await Track.updateMany({},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        fitnessPlans: {
          $map: {
            input: "$fitnessPlans",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { week: "$$this.month" }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $unset: "fitnessPlans.month" }
  ],
  { strict: false });
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UnXgWJzeyhS)

Comment: Tried this, now getting the error `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$set' in '0.$set' is not valid for storage.`

Comment: Ah never mind, I checked the playground and I saw you had set `multi: true` and when I used that in place of `strict: false` it seems to be working.

Comment: multi: true is not needed when you use updateMany method,  and playground is not supporting updateMany method.

Comment: Got it. The migration did run successfully (it's listed as 'up') but unfortunately it seems the existing documents still have the month fields and no week field.

Comment: you are missing something, print query response.

Comment: The response from the updateMany query? Looks like this: `{ n: 19, nModified: 19, ok: 1 }`

Comment: okay so what is the issue? that is correct response, it shows 19 records has been modified successfully.

Comment: Except when I look at the records in the db, they still have a `month` field and no `week` field

Comment: It should work i have tested in my PC too, i am sure are missing something. make sure you are checking in right database collection.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at the response object when loading the tracks in the frontend of my app, and there is still a month field and no week field. This is an issue because it then causes a crash when the system looks for week and can't find it.

Comment: probably collection or database is wrong, otherwise you can see working playground and you can try this query direct in mongod shell or any mongo query editor.